# CSS headers which zoom out when the page isscrolled

Tags: css, header

how to design an persistent header which zoom's out(i.e. becomes small ) when scrolling down

P.s:- if possible suggest an example site with code and demo

Comment: Any exmaple or code tried ?

Comment: What did you try before ?

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find what you are looking for here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/16/on-scroll-header-effects/ or here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/06/on-scroll-animated-header/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to detect scrolling, then try to add or remove some css code.

Javascript example function :

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Here an example :

http://callmenick.com/2014/02/18/create-an-animated-resizing-header-on-scroll/

### [Demo](http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/resize-header-on-scroll/)